# retrieve value from Parameters Map sent by Javascript Function generated by p:remoteCommand does not work

Tags: spring, jsf, dictionary, primefaces, httprequest

Many tickets had been raised related to this issue :

1. [How do you pass parameters(from javascript) into remoteCommand(& then send it to backing beans)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497750/how-do-you-pass-parametersfrom-javascript-into-remotecommand-then-send-it-to)
2. [Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)
3. [Supplying parameters through p:remoteCommand to a Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765022/supplying-parameters-through-premotecommand-to-a-spring-bean)

The nearest Issue to this ticket is the last one ( [Supplying parameters through p:remoteCommand to a Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765022/supplying-parameters-through-premotecommand-to-a-spring-bean) )

Indeed , i have as:

JSF view:

```
<h:form>
   <p:remoteCommand name="myFn" actionListner="#{personBean.updateProfile}" />
</h:form>
```

Spring managed bean:

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
@Qualifier("personBean")
    public class PersonBean{

         //.............
    @Value("#{request.getParameter('idSelected')}")
     private Long idSelected;
         //.................

        public void  updateProfile(){
                 // print parameters' map [key1=value1,key2=value2,....]
                System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap());


         }
    }
```

Calling the Javascript Function `myFn({idSelected:670})` triggers the Backing Bean method `updateProfile`, since , the console prints :

```
 {execution=e6s2,idSelected=670, javax.faces.partial.ajax=true,javax.faces.source=j_idt105:j_idt106,....}
```

As you note `idSelected` has been passed successfully as parameter . 
However  :

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get('idSelected')` return `null` .

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get('idSelected'); 
// return NULL !!!
```

If the Type of Paramters Map is `Map<String,String>` , why there is no
value even the printing of the whole map displays `idSelected=670` ?

if `.get('idSelected')` [ in general `.get(<KEY>)`] does not work ,
there is another way to retrieve the param-value given the
param-name(key)?

Comment: Did you try double quotes around isSelected instead of single ones?

Comment: How do you pass the request parameter named `idSelected` through the given `<p:remoteCommand>` as specified with this annotation `@Value("#{request.getParameter('idSelected')}")?`

Comment: @Value("#{request.getParameter('idSelected')}") I guess request here is is itself not populated when this annotation is evaluated.
So it is empty-default Request.Can You check when exactly is this annotation evaluated ?